# Reacting to changes in a draggable PowerCharts graph

Tags: javascript, dom-events, fusioncharts

I'm using the [drag-able line chart from the FusionCharts PowerCharts package](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/powercharts/Gallery/DragableCharts/Dragline.html).

I need to get the data of the graph and send it to server-side for further processing after user has moved a draggable point. This is easy to do with the Submit-button built in to the graph but I want this to happen without the user having to click the Submit button.

Based on the documentation (especially on the the [events](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/JavaScript/API/Events.html)) it seems that the chart will not fire any events when the user has moved a point in the graph.

So now I'm trying to figure out the best way to get notified of the user-made changes to the graph?

One option would be to periodically call a JS function that would get the graph's data and check if it has changed since the last check. However this feels pretty ugly and inefficient and I don't currently know how to implement the continuous polling in JS.

I'm now leaning towards just to listening for a mouse up event on the element where the graph is and then check changes to previous state of the graph. This should work although the user will probably often click on the graph without actually dragging a point in it.

Am I missing some other obvious solutions here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things I would like to put forward before we reach solution:

1. Polling is always a bad idea. And polling at a short interval is worse. However, if you do not need to react spontaneously on drag of the data-point, a high-interval polling will do. For your information, polling is done on JavaScript either by using [`setInterval`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) function or by using recursive [`setTimeout`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp).
2. In case you want to track  mouse events, keep a note that in case you are rendering Flash charts, you need to ensure that the `wMode` (window mode) parameter of the chart is NOT set to "window". In "window" wMode, the browser does not track mouse-events when hovered over the chart. To change `wMode` of a chart, ensure you execute `chartInstance.setTransparent(false)` or `chartInstance.setTransparent(true)` before rendering the chart.

The mouse-event method that you have planned will not help you since you will not know whether user had clicked on the data-point. Hence this method is ruled out.

Thus, you are left with polling. :(

**Update (after the first comment by Janne):**
Using a combination of both to check for data change when drag event occurs on chart is the right solution.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I might still go with the mouse tracking and just check whether the chart data has changed since the last mouse click to determine whether the user changed anything. By the way, since you work at FusionCharts, do you know if there are any plans to make the draggable charts fire events when user clicks on data points?

Comment: There are plans. It is not so far away. But I am unsure of dates.